# I am trying to print the browser name on PHP using the browser() function and all it prints is "Default browser" on every browser I have

Tags: php, html, function, browser, default

This is the code:

[image: code]

I am trying to learn PHP on YouTube and on one tutorial I saw the guy printing his browser detail using the browser function. When I did the same thing he did all I print is just "Default browser".

Comment: Read the "notes" section here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php . Have you got the file it mentions?

Comment: check what @ADyson said and in addition to that, in my opinion, checking browser capabilities from the backend is prone to errors and false information.

Comment: In general: reading the documentation of a function (or tool) you want to use typically reveals a lot of important information. Especially if you also consider the examples it offers ...

Comment: Also as per the [ask] guide please don't post images of your code. There is absolutely no reason you can't paste it as text, which, in general, is far more useful for people who want to help you - see that guide for reasons why. Please also take the [tour] to get a better general idea of how this site works. Thanks.